# Javascript to stop HTML5 video playback on modal window close

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, html5-video

I've got a html5 video element on a modal window.  When I close the window the video continues to play.  I'm a total newbie to JS.  Is there an easy way to tie a video playback stop function to the window close button?  Below is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Modal Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#showSimpleModal").click(function() {
            $("div#simpleModal").addClass("show");
            return false;   
        });

        $("#closeSimple").click(function() {
            $("div#simpleModal").removeClass("show");
            return false;                   
        });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">

div#simpleModal
{
    position:absolute; 
    top: 40px; 
    width: 320px; 
    left: 170px; 
    border: solid 1px #bbb;     
    padding: 20px; 
    background: #fff; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); 
    opacity: 0.0; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.0s ease-out; z-index: 0;
}

div#simpleModal.show
{
    opacity: 1.0; 
    z-index: 100;        
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="" id="showSimpleModal">Show Modal</a>

<div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
<video width="320"  height="240" src="Davis_5109iPadFig3.m4v" controls="controls"> </video>
<a href="" id="closeSimple">Close</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any input greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 75):

I'm using the following trick to stop HTML5 video. pause() the video on modal close and set currentTime = 0;

```
<script>
     var video = document.getElementById("myVideoPlayer");
     function stopVideo(){
          video.pause();
          video.currentTime = 0;
     }
</script>
```

Now you can use stopVideo() method to stop HTML5 video. Like,

```
$("#stop").on('click', function(){
    stopVideo();
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The other answers pause the playback rather than stopping it. Thank you!

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. It looks correct, but it wouldn't pause or stop the videos.

Comment: @RolandiXor can you show us your code snippet ? By the phrase " it wouldn't pause or stop the videos" it looks like you have multiple videos. If you accidentally gave same id's for all video tag you may not get desired functionalities.

Comment: @way2vin I used different ids but this method didn't work. The one above yours did. BTW does your method require jquery? I ask because I notice you are using "$".

Comment: @RolandiXor yes, in my example I have used jquery. It not important u can use pure javascript for the purpose.

Comment: For those using jQuery, please take note of Simon's answer below: use `[0].pause()` to reference the video element.

Answer (score 58):

I searched all over the internet for an answer for this question. none worked for me except this code. Guaranteed. It work perfectly.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
$('video').trigger('pause');
});
```

Comment: $('video').trigger('pause'); is the way I went! Worked perfectly!

Comment: This is the one that did the trick for me, but I believe it may require jquery (which I'm using because of bootstrap), so you may want to mention that.

Comment: if you use `$('video').get(0).load();` it stops playback too and works just fine

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the only solution..

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is very helpful :)

Answer (score 38):

I'm not sure whether ZohoGorganzola's solution is correct; however, you may want to try getting at the element directly rather than trying to invoke a method on the jQuery collection, so instead of

```
$("#videoContainer").pause();
```

try

```
$("#videoContainer")[0].pause();
```

Comment: Thanks It helped me . the second one worked for me. [0] was the essential part of method :)))

Comment: For anyone finds their way here, this works in code, but for some reason it doesn't in the console (at least not from Chrome). If you get an error while testing, try it anyway in your actual code, it should work.

Answer (score 10):

When you close the video you just need to pause it.

```
$("#closeSimple").click(function() {
    $("div#simpleModal").removeClass("show");
    $("#videoContainer")[0].pause();
    return false;                   
});

<video id="videoContainer" width="320" height="240" src="Davis_5109iPadFig3.m4v" controls="controls"> </video>
```

Also, for reference, here's the Opera [documentation for scripting video controls](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/introduction-html5-video/#scripting).

Answer (score 6):

The right answer is : `$("#videoContainer")[0].pause();`

Comment: have you tested this on an iPad. Seems like when you pop the modal back up, the video does not seem to load again.

Comment: Okk this solution Works.. make sure to put [0] in the method.. else it wont stop the Video.  Thanks

Comment: @Carlos did you find the solution for your comment? I'm getting the same error

Comment: @climboid, we actually had to go with a different solution (VideoJS) because of this issue.  There may be better support now for HTML5 video and Modal, thought if it still happening, probably not.

Comment: @climboid, My solution is on JS fiddle for the Video JS and iPad solution. http://jsfiddle.net/UGS2U/1/

Comment: Thanks @Carlos, I ended up pausing the video and then closing the modal. I believe I need more video formats to solve my case but for the question answered that worked nice.

Answer (score 5):

Have a try:

```js
function stop(){
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    video.load();
}
```

Comment: Why should the OP use this code? Could you expand you answer with an explanation?

Comment: From google dev: "Note: Calling video.pause() isn't the only way to interrupt a video. You can entirely reset the video playback state, including the buffer, with video.load() and video.src..." (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showSimpleModal").click(function() {
        $("div#simpleModal").addClass("show");
        $("#videoContainer")[0].play();
        return false;   
    });

    $("#closeSimple").click(function() {
        $("div#simpleModal").removeClass("show");
        $("#videoContainer")[0].pause();
        return false;                   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this issue with videos embedded using the `<object>` tag, the function you want is Quicktime's `element.Stop();` For example, to stop any and all playing movies, use:

```
var videos = $("object");

for (var i=0; i < videos.length; i++)
{
    if (videos[i].Stop) { videos[i].Stop(); }
}
```

Note the non-standard capital "S" on Stop();

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me using 4.1 video.js CDN.  This code kills the video playing in a modal when the (`.closemodal`) is clicked.  I had 3 videos.  Someone else can refactor.

```
var myPlayer = videojs("my_video_1");
var myPlayer2 = videojs("my_video_2");
var myPlayer3 = videojs("my_video_3");
$(".closemodal").click(function(){
   myPlayer.pause();
myPlayer2.pause();
myPlayer3.pause();
});
});
```

as per their [Api](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api.md) docs.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to stop the video using "get(0)" (Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object):

```
$("#closeSimple").click(function() {
    $("div#simpleModal").removeClass("show");
    $("#videoContainer").get(0).pause();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you play streaming video with webRtc you must delete the tracks from de the stream and set src Object to null.

Answer (score -1):

// modal <div id='image-modal' ....>  youtube player
//or
// modal <div id='image-modal' ....>  video player

```
$('#image-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $("#image-modal iframe").attr("src", $("#image-modal iframe").attr("src"));
    $("#image-modal video").attr("src", $("#image-modal video").attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address anything from the question, and isn't clear what it's trying to communicate in general. What's the intention? What is the snippet supposed to do? Why and how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: There definitely has got to be a better solution.