# How to play video as popup while clicking on a button in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here i embedded my code. Actually i want to play video as popup while clicking on a button in html by using java script. This code is working but video is still playing in background.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  popup.play(true)
}
```

```css
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center">
  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><button>Preview</button>
    <video class="popuptext" id="myPopup" style="width:800px;">
    <source src="dolby-atmos-intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Do you mean the video plays from the start before clicking on button?

Comment: you can use the bootstrap modal here..good tutorial http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-embed-youtube-video-inside-bootstrap-modal.php and

Comment: @Ridhik Try bootstrap modal pop ups. It's very elegant and needs less code.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958132/javascript-to-stop-html5-video-playback-on-modal-window-close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle video play/pause.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.popup .popuptext {
visibility: hidden;
background-color: #555;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 8px 0;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 125%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -80px;
}
.popup .show {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;} 
to {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()" ><button>Preview</button>
<video class="popuptext" id="myPopup" style="width:800px;" >
<source src="dolby-atmos-intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
popup.classList.toggle("show");

if (popup.paused){ 
    popup.play(); 
    }
  else{ 
    popup.pause();
    }
 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is working,But it doesn't close when i click ESC key on keyboard

Comment: write a listener for esc key and check for pop and close it it is opened

Comment: I tried it,But its not working. Can you add that in snippet

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<button onclick="openIt()">preview</button>

<script>
function openIt(){
    window.open("video Url");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  popup.play(true)
}
```

```css
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<body style="text-align:center">
  <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><button>Preview</button>
    <video class="popuptext" id="myPopup" style="width:800px;">
    <source src="dolby-atmos-intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
 </body>
```