# How to embed video link in email so that the recipient can play it immediately without going through the download screen

Tags: html, iis, video, video-streaming

I'm not sure "which wall to put my ladder against" here or even the correct terminology for what I am attempting to do.
I have developed software for an agricultural research company over a number of years.
We have an android application that performs many functions including uploading photos from the field (eg crop growth stages) along with meta data (trial number, comment, agronomist name).
These are included in reports automatically emailed out daily to my client's clients.

Recently we have added video capture (20 seconds max, 4 or 5 Mb at 480p) and these are now included in the daily reports.

My client is happy with this but doesn't like the way that clicking on the image in the report takes the end client to a download page first and then they have to click on the downloaded file.
They want the end client to click on the video and have it play immediately.

Here is a typical piece of HTML in the email body:

```
<td> 
  <a href='http://<our web site>/GoTrialImages/HiRes/KA21_0001_20230213_124221_ACE_Video.mp4'>
  <img src='http://<our web site>/GoTrialImages/LoRes/KA21_0001_20230213_124221_ACE.jpg'>
</td>
```

Where the jpg has been grabbed as a frame out of the mp4 file in the android app and uploaded along with the mp4 file.

We are storing all the jpg and mp4 files on our own server without any problems and we have full control over the IIS service we are running.
We are also able to code and install our own app under IIS (though so far this has only been api's to upload and download data between the central system and the android app)

Can someone please point me in the right direction to start researching.

1. Some clever piece of HTML would be wonderful but unlikely
2. Maybe a service similar to YouTube the way a video is streamed immediately on clicking
3. Some clever C# code I could install in our own IIS server
4. Any thing else ?

Also - what is the correct terminology for what I am attempting to do ?

Many thanks in advance
Tony

Comment: have you tried adding a `<video>` tag to the email with the still as the poster image, or have the link to your website target a page with a video tag on?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have .mp4 mime type available in iis

You can use html, css and JavaScript to accomplish your requirement as shown below:
[How to play video as popup while clicking on a button in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497409/how-to-play-video-as-popup-while-clicking-on-a-button-in-html)

Comment: Many thanks - I'll start studying in that direction. (We've added the mp4 mime type to the site under IIS)
Tony